# Sorting array based on custom priority of one attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

I'm using jQuery to parse a JSON file of employees, which contains their name, department, subdepartment, and some other details.

e.g.:

```
[
{
  "LAST":"Betsy",
  "FIRST":"Jackson",
  "DEPT":"Customer Service",
  "SUBDEPT":"Tech Support",
  "JOINED":"02/94",
  "TITLE":"Technical Customer Service Representative",
  "RESIDENCE":"Someplace",
  "HOBBIES":"Reading, Walking, Sleeping"
},
{
  "LAST":"Sally",
  "FIRST":"Smith",
  "DEPT":"Customer Service",
  "SUBDEPT":"Installation Customer Service Representative",
  "JOINED":"01/04",
  "TITLE":"Technical Customer Service Representative",
  "RESIDENCE":"Someplace",
  "HOBBIES":"Reading, Walking, Sleeping"
},
]
```

I'm trying to build an application where users can click on the name of an employee and see a refresh of results where every employee in that employee's department is shown, organized by the sub-departments, and scrolled-down to the given employee.

I've successfully generated a list of employee names, with data-* attributes to hold their department and sub-department. When an employee name is clicked, I've been able to parse the JSON file a second time return all the employees who are also in that department, and build a grid, and then push the entire matching employee object into a new array called "results."

note: dept = data-dept passed by jquery selector..

```
$.each(data, function(i, employee) { 
    if (employee.DEPT == dept) {
    var employeetext = '<span class="name">'
     + employee.FIRST+' '+ employee.LAST+'</span>',
     employee.JOINED, 
     employee.TITLE, 
     employee.RESIDENCE, 
     '...', 
     employee.HOBBIES;  

        $('#employees').append('<div class="employee_block"><img src="" width="85" height="113">' + employeetext + '.</div>');  

        results.push(employee); 
}
}) // end stepping through employees
```

However, I need to build the grid based on a new sorted order from the array, rather than y the alphabetical that is being used now. I need to split the results by sub-department, according to a priority that is not alphabetical, but rather a custom order which I'm hoping to define in a separate object (would this be a "relational database?") e.g:

```
var subdeptorder =  [
{
    "DEPT": "Marketing",
    "SUBDEPTS": ["Administration", "Purchasing", "Advertising", "PR"]
},
{
    "DEPT": "Sales",
    "SUBDEPTS": ["Administration", "Business Development"]
}
]
```

So I need to sort the "results" array according to the employee's department (and that department's subdepartment order) within it.

How do I write a comparison function to re-sort the "results" array according to a priority established in a separate object?

Comment: use .sort and reference the separate object in the logic that returns -1 0 or 1 relative to the nodes currently being sorted.

Comment: Thanks. I should mention this will be my first time using .sort at all, so any addl. guidance is appreciated!

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: If at all, it's a duplicate of [Sorting on a custom order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872554/sorting-on-a-custom-order)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the separate object like this:

```
var subdeptorder = {
    "Marketing": ["Administration", "Purchasing", "Advertising", "PR"],
    "Sales": ["Administration", "Business Development"]
};
```

Then you can sort the data like so:

```
var dept = …; // the chosen one

var results = $.grep(data, function(employee) {
        return employee.DEPT = dept;
    }),
    order = subdeptorder[dept];
results.sort(function(a, b) {
    // sort them by the indices of their SUBDEPTs in the order array
    return $.inArray(a.SUBDEPT, order) - $.inArray(b.SUBDEPT, order);
});
$.each(results, function(i, employee) { 
     $('#employees').append('<div class="employee_block"><img src="" width="85" height="113">' + [
         '<span class="name">'+employee.FIRST+' '+employee.LAST+'</span>',
         employee.JOINED,
         employee.TITLE,
         employee.RESIDENCE,
         '…',
         employee.HOBBIES
     ].join(' ') + '.</div>');
});
```

See [Sorting on a custom order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872554/sorting-on-a-custom-order/14872766#14872766) for an optimised version (not using `$.inArray` for the index every time).

Comment: I only want to return employee.DEPT = dept if they match, so I wrapped that in a conditional. But this is still printing them in alphabetical order *after* the first employee. I can't figure out how it's picking the first employee just yet, with the above code. I set up my deptorder array (calling it deptorder now since it assigns dept and subdept order), it just doesn't seem to be using it yet. (also, comma needed after employee.TITLE)

Comment: I can tell "order" is right, because I can see it in log..
    
but the results array is not being sorted according this. It's still printing them according to the alphabetical order of the employees last name.

Comment: The [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) condition is done by `grep`, which is independent from the sorting task. Thanks for spotting the missing comma. My mistake was confusing the odd parameter order of [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray), I should've used the [native `indexOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) better. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Fixing the order of parameters in inArray did the trick for separating my sub-sections by priority set in my subdeptorder object. THANKS! For some reason I still need to wrap the return inside grep with a conditional in order to return only employees whose department is the same as the department of the employee selected. But this gets me by!

Comment: I will need to do another round of this and order the employees within each subsection according to either a priority set in the JSON or by another separate object. Not sure if that warrants another question on stack (if I get stuck) or if I can roll it into this question?