# How to sort an array elements?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to sort an array of string in an angular application that for example contains :

`names = ["Eve","Jhon","Maria","Jadon"]` and I want to sort them in this `order : ["Maria", "Eve", "Jadon", "Jhon"]`
I tried

```
names.sort();
```

But this will order it into an  ascending order but for me I want to choose the order as I want it to be ! as if I have a table and I want to  sort it's header's `items=["id","name","email","fullname","tel"]` to `["name","id","email","tel","fullname"]`.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: How would you programatically define "this order" ?

Comment: a random order? sure I can not understand the logic of your order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting on a custom order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872554/sorting-on-a-custom-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this,

```
  const arrToSort = ["Eve","Jhon","Maria","Jadon"]
  
  const priority = ["Maria", "Eve", "Jadon", "Jhon"];

  const sortedObj = arrToSort.sort((a, b) => {
    const indexOfA = priority.indexOf(a);
    const indexOfB = priority.indexOf(b);
    if (indexOfA < indexOfB) return -1;
    if (indexOfA > indexOfB) return 1;
    return 0;
  });

  console.log(sortedObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example how you can create custom sorter function to sort by predefined ordered array

```js
const THIS_ORDER = ["Maria", "Eve", "Jadon", "Jhon"] 

const data = ["Eve","Jhon","Maria","Jadon"];

const sorter = (a, b) => THIS_ORDER.indexOf(a) - THIS_ORDER.indexOf(b)

const result = data.sort(sorter)

console.log(result)
```