# Sorting by specific values in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Newbie to Typescript here. I previously coded mostly in scala. Is there a way to sort by specific values in typescript? This is what I might do in scala previously:

```
Seq("bbb", "foo", "bar", "aaa", "hello", "world", "ccc").sortBy { word =>
  word match {
    case "hello" => 0
    case "bar" => 1
    case "foo" => 2
    case "world" => 3
    case _ => 4
  }
} // val res1: Seq[String] = List(hello, bar, foo, world, bbb, aaa, ccc)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting on a custom order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872554/sorting-on-a-custom-order)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The typescript is responsible for types and not for sorting, in this case, the solution can be found in the js area

```js
console.log(
["bbb", "foo", "bar", "aaa", "hello", "world","ccc"].sort((word: string, nextWord: string) => {
  const test = (value: string):number => {
    switch (value){
      case "hello" : return 0;
      case "bar" : return 1;
      case "foo" : return 2;
      case "world" : return 3
      default : return Infinity; 
    }}
  if (test(word) < test(nextWord)) return -1
  if (test(word) > test(nextWord)) return 1
  return 0
}
))
```

Comment: Please just vote to close questions asking about "how to do X in TypeScript" as duplicates of their JavaScript equivalents. We don't need to have every JavaScript question reanswered as TypeScript questions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey OK. Can you show me an answer for a similar question first? I can trasform my answer to TS.