# Sort array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

As an absolute javascript beginner, I am currently practicing on a todo app. The entries should be sorted by title, date, status and priority by clicking on the column header.
Attached is my attempt, however I seem to be doing something wrong. Can anyone help me with this?

```
const todos = [
  {id: 1, duedate: "2023-06-30", title: "Javascript Project 1", description: "first try", prio: 1, state: "done"}
];

const titleSort = document.getElementById("sort-title");

function sortTitle(a, b) {
  // alert("Titel sortieren");

  const titleA = a.title.toUpperCase();
  const titleB = b.title.toUpperCase();

  let comparison = 0;
  if (titleA > titleB) {
    comparison = 1;
  } else if (titleA < titleB) {
    comparison = -1;
  }
  return comparison;
}

titleSort.addEventListener("click", sortTitle);
```

Comment: You forgot to sort the array. Do you expect `titleSort.addEventListener` to sort something when you pass a comparison function?

Comment: The event listener will pass the `event` object to your `sortTitle` function... Not the `todos` array. Then, your `return` will end nowhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting on a custom order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872554/sorting-on-a-custom-order)

Comment: @AndyRay: The issue is not the sort function, but how it is used.

Answer (score 2):

The event listener will pass the `event` object to your `sortTitle` function... Not the `todos` array. Then, your return will end nowhere.

So... To the event listener, you have to pass a function to be executed. In that function, you specify what array to sort and where to return it.

```js
const todos = [
  {id: 1, duedate: "2023-06-30", title: "Javascript Project 2", description: "second try", prio: 1, state: "done"},
  {id: 1, duedate: "2023-06-30", title: "Javascript Project 3", description: "third try", prio: 1, state: "done"},
  {id: 1, duedate: "2023-06-30", title: "Javascript Project 1", description: "first try", prio: 1, state: "done"}
];

const titleSort = document.getElementById("sort-title");

function sortTitle(array) {
  
  return array.sort((a,b) => {

    const titleA = a.title.toUpperCase();
    const titleB = b.title.toUpperCase();

    let comparison = 0;
    if (titleA > titleB) {
      comparison = 1;
    } else if (titleA < titleB) {
      comparison = -1;
    }
    return comparison;
  })
}

// I don't know where you want to return the sorted array... So I just console logged it.
titleSort.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(sortTitle(todos)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<button id='sort-title'>Sort me</button>
```

Comment: This works wonderfully and your solution has helped me a lot! Now the sorted array should be returned to the list. This I have created with template strings:<div class="title">${todo.title}</div>. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: There certainly is existing documentation about your templating system.